# How to get rid of diacritics on my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I searched Google and SU for my problem, but everybody seems to want to add diacritics, while I *don't* want them.

I'm using Windows 7 and have a US keyboard installed, *not* the international version. Despite that some keys, like <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> are used for diacritics, which means that I have to type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> to get a double quote. How do I get rid of this? My other PC, with the same settings, doesn't show this behavior.

**edit** re Stefan's answer
I don't see the icon Stefan refers to in my taskbar, probably because I have [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) installed. But this is a screenshot of the Input Languages dialog, there are no other keyboards installed:

[image]

Comment: Can you verify that you have selected the correct EN (US) version? Here is a picture showing the popup which appears when you click on the little keyboard icon in the taskbar. It should be set to "US", not "International" as in the picture. ![Keyboard settings popup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GPga9.png)

Comment: @stevenvh Try right-clicking on empty task bar area, and see if there's an option called "Language Bar" under "Toolbars" at the top of the menu.

Comment: @Darth - Nope, there isn't one. But I found the solution, see my answer. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: Based on your answers on EE.SE, I bet you could just slap a couple op-amps and resistors in your keyboard somewhere to eliminate them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found it. Apparently removing the other keyboard and selecting the US version doesn't disable the other one, you still have to switch manually. Those who use *Classic Shell*, like me, may not see the keyboard icon, but you can use a keyboard combination for the switch.

[image]

A newly added keyboard will show under the tab *Advanced Key Settings* with no key sequence assigned. Temporarily assign one, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, and use the combination to activate the new keyboard layout. If you don't have other keyboards configured you can remove the key sequence again.